# slow query time for mysql select

Tags: mysql, performance, latitude-longitude

I am very new to MySQL and databases in general but I have a query that seems to be taking a long time. I am finding locations from a location database of about 700,000 that are within 5 miles of another location using lat and lon coordinates. The problem is, it's taking 2.12 seconds for the query and I'm worried once I start getting traffic, MySQL will jam. Here is my code:

```
SELECT *,((ACOS(SIN(44.4726 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(44.4726 * PI() /          180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((-93.1785 - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 *   1.1515) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance<=5 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 30;
```

I have the lat and lon fields indexed but it still takes a long time. Is this to be expected with what I'm asking the server to do? Could I speed it up by adding

```
WHERE state = "$state"
```

And if so where would I add that in the Select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is going to seq scan the entire table because there's really not a filter on it that doesn't derive from a calculated value (distance).  Adding a where clause that filters by an indexed column will definitely help eliminate some overhead, but only if the DB believes that there's enough data in the table to warrant using the index instead of the table.  Thus, make sure you analyze it as well.

The logic with the distance being in the query is incredibly ugly, but I can see why you wouldn't want to transmit 700k+ rows over the wire every time you select from the table.  It looks like you may be doing spatial calculations and might be wise to investigate spatial data types and indexes.

Ed: Also, your question about a where clause...

```
select fields [aggregate fields]
from table
where where clause
group by fields
having having clause
```

Comment: I have read a few posts on here about spatial data types with lat and lon coordinates but also read that it's a bad idea so decided to try to make what I have work. Also, I may sound like I have more knowledge about this than what I actually have...lol. So could you dumb down the where clause? I just want to know how to add "WHERE column = $variable" and how to include that in my current query string

Comment: I got it!!! I put an index on states and changed my code to this `....AS distance FROM locations WHERE state = 'mn' HAVING distance.....` . It took my query from 2.12 sec to .262 sec. I'm not going to complain about that. I may have a problem if a city is right on the border of 2 states because it won't find locations in the bordering state. But until I can come up with something more permanent, I'm very happy. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the calculation in the query?  Logic like that should not be in the DAL.

I'd suggest getting just the columns you need, then doing the calculate in your code which would allow you to only calculate the parts without the lat and long once (SIN(44.4726 * PI() / 180) for example), then just loop the results and add in the lat and long as appropriate.

Comment: Not really understanding. I start out with a known lat and lon location. I want to query the table of locations against those coordinates using the distance formula. I don't know how to do that without querying the database and using those lat and lon numbers against my known lat and lon numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about how this type of querying is usually done so feel free to disregard my suggestion but suppose your application were to take the input {lat,lon} and expand it by 5 miles in each direction (north, east, south and west). Then, your query could select only those records having a lat and long between the upper and lower bounds.

You still have to do the distance calculation but you will have eliminated records that couldn't possibly match and so, you should reduce the overhead of the query. Furthermore, if you have an index on lat and long, it mysql should be able to use these.

I may have misunderstood the geometry, as I say, I have no experience in the area but it might be a useful optimisation in addtion to the other suggestions.